# How to add place holder in edittext inside listview

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am working with android. I had created a list view with edit text using array adapter.Now How can I add text like placeholder in each textfield ???? Also on click it must disappear...How can I do this please help me ,thanks

Comment: Are you talking about  android:hint="Hint Message"

Comment: I am using array list . then how can I placed hint to each textfield?

Comment: <EditText 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hint Message">

Comment: I am using edit text inside custom listview.So I need diff hint for each field.

Comment: In getView() you will now the current view location. Use ViewHolder Pattern. Then using the current position you can update the hint like viewHolder.hintMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.hintMessage); viewHolder.hintMessage.setHint(yourarray[position].getXXXX);

Comment: @doubter upload your all code

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong then you just need to create one `String ArrayList` with your all the hints and  passed this `ArrayList` to your Adapter and in `getView()` methods you can get Hint from `ArrayList` and set to `EditText`.

Comment: myItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
                listItem.caption = "Caption";
                myItems.add(listItem);
            }

Comment: here is my code i am used . how can I pass values to this array??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for the [`hint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint) attribute or the corresponding [`setHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
method.

Comment: I am using array list . then how can I placed hint to each textfield??